# Inheritance in C

Tags: c, inheritance

I am playing with implementing inheritance in C. I wrote the following two variations of it. Method 1 crashes while running the program, but Method 2 works fine. What am I doing wrong in Method 1?

### Method 1:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct base_class
{
    int a;
}Base;

typedef struct derived_class
{
    int b;
    Base *base_ptr;
}Derived;

int main(void){
    Derived *der_ptr;
    der_ptr = (Derived *)malloc(sizeof(Derived));
    der_ptr->b = 5;
    der_ptr->base_ptr->a=10;

    printf("%d %d",der_ptr->b,der_ptr->base_ptr->a);
}
```

### Method 2:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct base_class
{
    int a;
}Base;

typedef struct derived_class
{
    int b;
    Base base_ptr;
}Derived;

int main(void){
    Derived *der_ptr;
    der_ptr = (Derived *)malloc(sizeof(Derived));
    der_ptr->b = 5;
    der_ptr->base_ptr.a=10;

    printf("%d %d",der_ptr->b,der_ptr->base_ptr.a);
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, swapping the elements of `struct derived_class` in Method 2 would allow you to safely cast `Derived *` to `Base *`.

Comment: Not a duplicate but maybe useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26207800/1392132

Answer (score 5):

Method 1 crashes because of this line of code:

```
der_ptr->base_ptr->a=10;
```

Ask yourself:  What is the value of `der_ptr->base_ptr`?

Answer (score 4):

Nothing wrong in method 2, but it depends on what are you trying to achieve.

In method 1 however, you are never allocating space for the pointer `Base *base_ptr` and then you are dereferencing it, that is why your program is crashing.

This, and notice that i've removed the cast because while it's needed in c++, it's not needed in c

```
der_ptr = malloc(sizeof(Derived));
```

is allocating space for one `int` and one pointer, so `sizeof(Derived) = sizeof(int) + sizeof(void *)`, if you want to access the `a` member of `base_ptr` you need to allocate space for it to, after allocating for the `der_ptr` and checking that allocation was successful, you then allocate for it's `base_ptr` member, like this

```
der_ptr->base_ptr = malloc(sizeof(Base));
```

and then you can access `base_ptr`'s `a` member.

Also, please note that unlike the `new` operator in c++ which does some of it's exception handling thing when it fails, in c you should check that `malloc` returned a valid pointer, on failure it returns `NULL`.

So, your method 1 should work like this

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct base_class
{
    int a;
} Base;

/*
  typedef struct derived_class
  {
      int b;
      Base *base_ptr;
  } Derived;
*/

/* the order matters, this way you can cast Derived to Base */
typedef struct derived_class
{
    Base *base_ptr;
    int b;
} Derived;

int main(void) {
    Derived *der_ptr;

    der_ptr = malloc(sizeof(Derived));
    if (der_ptr == NULL)
        return 1;

    der_ptr->b        = 5;
    der_ptr->base_ptr = malloc(sizeof(Base));
    if (der_ptr->base_ptr == NULL)
    {
        free(der_ptr);
        return 2;
    }
    der_ptr->base_ptr->a = 10;

    printf("%d %d", der_ptr->b, der_ptr->base_ptr->a);

    free(der_ptr->base_ptr);
    free(der_ptr);
}
```

and notice that you can also cast `Derived *` to `Base *` now that the members are in this order.

Comment: You are `free()`ing the memory in the wrong order.  But fixing that and mentioning what @duskwuff says in the comment (putting the base at the beginning) would make your answer almost perfect, I think.

Comment: @5gon12eder I was going out for some beer, but now that i am back, duh, that was a stupid mistake, and about the possibility of casting, good idea, i've fixed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already indicated you are not allocating storage for Base so Method 1 will cause random access to some location in memory.

If you are interested in implementing OO like interfaces and higher level programming in C then I recommend taking a good look at [libCello](http://libcello.org), you will be surprised at the expressiveness afforded.